# How to get the drop target background effect in sidebars on macOS using SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui, drag-and-drop, sidebar

I have a SwiftUI List that's a sidebar on macOS. For its items I have added the [dropDesternation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamictablerowcontent/dropdestination(for:action:)) modifier like this:

```
.dropDestination(for: URL.self) { urls, _ in
      for url in urls {
          //... adding urls to destination
      }
}

return true
} isTargeted: { inDropArea in
      if inDropArea {
          highlightedItem = item
      } else {
          highlightedItem = nil
    }
}
```

By default if the cursor is above the item I get no effect, but I want the same effect like using NSOutlineView in AppKit. Here's an example from the Finder:

[image: Drag and drop in the Finder sidebar]

As you can see I have implemented `highlightedItem` in the code above. I can use it to check if an item is targeted and draw a background:

```
 .background {
       if item == highlightedItem {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
       }
}
```

But that does not look quite the same:

[image: own implementation of sidebar drop target]

Interestingly the effect I want is the same you get if you use a selection for the sidebar list like: `List(selection: $selectedItem)`

There must be a native way to do this so I don't have to fake it and get something that does not look quite right.

Comment: "*But that does not look quite the same*", you mean the rectangle?

Comment: Yes. I want the same style as in the first screenshot. With lots of custom code it might work, but since you get it for free in other places, there might be an easy way to enable it for a drop destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*shufflingb*'s workaround is nice but can have performance side effects and I've found a simpler solution.

I've made a view for each list item and used `blistRowBackground()` for the background effect, not just `.background`:

```
struct SidebarItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @State private var isTargeted = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: item) {
            Label {
                Text(item.title)

            } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "folder")
            }
            .onDrop(of: [.image], isTargeted: $isTargeted, perform: { itemProviders in
            ...
            return true
            })
        }
        .listRowBackground(
            Color.secondary
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .opacity(isTargeted ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Having the `List` elements be selectable and triggering that selection temporarily seems to work quite nicely.

For example ...

```
let Bands: Array<String> = [
    "Beatles", "Rolling Stones", "Animals", "Beach Boys", "Doors",
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: String? = nil
    @State var dropSelectionCache: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Drag text on onto band to trigger highlighting")
            List(Bands, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { band in
                Text(band)
                    .dropDestination(for: String.self) { _, _ in
                        true
                    } isTargeted: { (isTarget: Bool) in
                        if isTarget {
                            dropSelectionCache = selection
                            withAnimation {
                                selection = band
                            }
                        } else {
                            withAnimation {
                                selection = dropSelectionCache
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a gif illustrating the code in operation on Ventura (apologies for slightly shakey screen recording - that's me an and not the code :-/ )

[image: Low res drag and drop showing code in operation]

Comment: Nice trick. I have bound quite many things to `selection` so I have to do some more stuff if I don't actually want to change the selection, but that's easy. Thanks for your time and answer!